# How I get ExoPlayer to resume a video in my Activity's onStart() method?

Tags: android, video, android-activity, exoplayer

I'm using ExoPlayer to play some mp4's from a URL. When the user click's the home button, or anything that causes the app to be removed from the user's view and then comes back to my app (and video activity) I want the video to resume where it left off. I tried implementing this by saving the video position in `onStop()` and then rebuilding the player and using `seekTo()` in `onStart()`. I have a check to see if my current exoplayer is null in `onStart()`, this check never passes however, so I think this is where the problem lies. How it's coded now my video never resumes. If I leave the app by pressing the home button `onStop()` gets called and then `onStart()` will get called when I go back into my app, however the video player remains black and never plays the video. If I remove the null check I get two instances of the video playing whenever I start a video from the main activity because it gets called both in `onCreate()` and `onStart()`. Is there a better method for getting the functionality that I want? Any help is appreciated!

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private long playerPosition;
    private String mp4Url;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_activity);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the video url
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mp4Url = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.VIDEO_URL);
        // Create an exoplayer instance and start playing video
        buildPlayer(mp4Url);

    }

    private void buildPlayer(String mp4Url) {
        // Create a default TrackSelector
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        // Create the player
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector); // no LoadControl?
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);

        // Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();

        // Bind player to the view
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

        // Create Uri from video location
        // TODO: should this be in some network class? Should I be appending APIKEY here?
        Uri mp4Uri = Uri.parse(mp4Url + "?api_key=" + BuildConfig.GIANTBOMB_API_KEY);
        Timber.v("Video url with api key: " + mp4Uri.toString());

        // Create another bandwidth meter for bandwidth during playback (not strictly necessary)
        DefaultBandwidthMeter playbackBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

        // DataSourceFactory to produce DataSource instances through which media data is loaded
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "GiantBombForAndroid"),
                playbackBandwidthMeter);

        // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        ExtractorMediaSource.EventListener eventListener = new ExtractorMediaSource.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadError(IOException error) {
                Timber.e("Error loading video from source");
            }
        };

        final MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mp4Uri,
                dataSourceFactory,
                extractorsFactory,
                mainHandler,
                eventListener);

        exoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);

        exoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                Timber.v("Listener-onLoadingChanged...");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                Timber.v("Listener-onPlayerStateChanged...");

            }

            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {
                Timber.v("Listener-onTimelineChanged...");

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
                // TODO: Do I need anything here?
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                Timber.v("Listener-onPlayerError...");
                exoPlayer.stop();
                exoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {
                Timber.v("Listener-onPositionDiscontinuity...");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {
                // TODO: Do I need anything here?
            }
        });
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Timber.v("onStart()...");
        if (exoPlayer == null) {
            Timber.v("No exoplayer instance, recreating...");
            buildPlayer(mp4Url);
            exoPlayer.seekTo(playerPosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Timber.v("onStop()...");
        //TODO: pull player creation code into it's own method so it can be called here as well
        playerPosition = exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        exoPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Timber.v("onDestroy()...");
        exoPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently you're calling release in `onStop()` which will null out all the important pieces of the player, but not the `exoPlayer` field (and destroy any state that you aren't keeping track of yourself).

There are a few different approaches. But no matter what you do, you'll likely want to keep track of some state yourself. Below I use them as fields, but they could also be placed in `onSavedInstanceState()`. In `onStop()` we're saving off two pieces of information and then pulling them out in `onStart()`. 1) The last position our player was in when pausing and 2) whether we should play when resumed. You can likely move your `seekTo` call out of the `if == null` block since you'll probably always want to resume from where you left off.:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // ...

    if (exoPlayer == null) {
        // init player
    }

    // Seek to the last position of the player.
    exoPlayer.seekTo(mLastPosition);

    // Put the player into the last state we were in.
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(mPlayVideoWhenForegrounded);

    // ...
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // ...

    // Store off if we were playing so we know if we should start when we're foregrounded again.
    mPlayVideoWhenForegrounded = exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();

    // Store off the last position our player was in before we paused it.
    mLastPosition = exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    // Pause the player
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);

    // ...
}
```

Now the other issue I see with your code sample is that `exoPlayer.release()` won't null out the field `exoPlayer`. So you could additionally add the line `exoPlayer = null` after `exoPlayer.release()` which should hopefully fix your issue of multiple exoPlayers. You could also move the `release()` call to `onDestroy()` but only if you know you're reinstantiating everything correctly.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to reinit player again. The following code is pretty enough:

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     if (player!=null) {
         player.stop();
          mLastPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
     }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     //initiatePlayer();
     if(mLastPosition!=0 && player!=null){
         player.seekTo(mLastPosition);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1. Get the player position in onPause.
2. initiate the palyer again in onResume and set seek to the last position of the player

   ```
    private void initiatePlayer() {

           try {

               exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);

               DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                       new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
               DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory =
                       new DefaultExtractorsFactory()
                               .setMp4ExtractorFlags(Mp4Extractor.FLAG_WORKAROUND_IGNORE_EDIT_LISTS);

               ProgressiveMediaSource progressiveMediaSource =
                       new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory)
                               .createMediaSource(videoUri);
               // playerView = new PlayerView(this);


               playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
               exoPlayer.prepare(progressiveMediaSource);
               exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

               PlayerControlView controlView = playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_controller);
               mFullScreenIcon = controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon);
               ImageView volumeControl = controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_volume);
               mFullScreenIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                       if(ORIENTATION ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                       }else {
                           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                       }

                       Timer mRestoreOrientation = new Timer();
                       mRestoreOrientation.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
                           }
                       }, 2000);
                   }
               });

               volumeControl.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                   float currentvolume = exoPlayer.getVolume();
                   if (currentvolume > 0f) {
                       previousVolume = currentvolume;
                       exoPlayer.setVolume(0f);
                       volumeControl.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_volume_off_white_24dp));
                   } else {
                       exoPlayer.setVolume(previousVolume);
                       volumeControl.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_volume_up_white_24dp));
                   }
               });

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               Log.d("MainExcep", e.getMessage());
           }
       }

    @Override
       protected void onPause() {
           super.onPause();
           if (exoPlayer!=null) {
               exoPlayer.stop();
               mLastPosition = exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
           }
       }


       @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           initiatePlayer();
           if(mLastPosition!=0){
               exoPlayer.seekTo(mLastPosition);
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if i minimize or try to move from the this player video app to another app. The video player app always starting play from 0. I was try and succesfully, the video player app playing video from the last current position when you minimalize or move to another app, and this it.

go to

```
private void buildPlayer(String mp4Url)
```

add

```
   player.seekTo(playbackPosition);
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(playbackPosition!=0 && player!=null){
        player.seekTo(playbackPosition);
        initializePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    player.stop();
    if(player != null && player.getPlayWhenReady()) {
        player.stop();
        playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
   player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
   player.stop();
   player.seekTo(0);
}
```

And you can try remove the

```
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

from

```
private void buildPlayer(String mp4Url)
```