# ExoPlayer not starting the video from a specific position (android studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, exoplayer

I want to start a video in the exoPlayer to start from a specific position on start. But always it starts from 0 position. After stoping the activity when it restarts it also not starts from current position and starts from initial position. Please help me.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class VideoDetails extends AppCompatActivity{

PlayerView playerView;
SimpleExoPlayer player;
String videoURL = "https://webflix1122.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cokestudio.mkv";
private long playBackPosition = 20000;
ProgressBar loadingBar;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_details);

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        loadingBar = findViewById(R.id.loading_bar);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);


        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "MyApp"));
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoURL));



        player.prepare(videoSource);
        player.seekTo(playBackPosition);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                switch (playbackState){
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                        loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                        loadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        playBackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        playerView.setPlayer(null);
        player.release();




    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        player.seekTo(playBackPosition);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player = null;
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to use `player.seekTo(...);` to start at a position other than 0, and you should consider using pause not stop, or rethink using `player.release();` if you want to keep the state. Here is a useful related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959176/how-i-get-exoplayer-to-resume-a-video-in-my-activitys-onstart-method

Comment: Note, not all file formats are seekable: https://exoplayer.dev/progressive.html#enabling-constant-bitrate-seeking